# bash variable capture stderr and stdout separately or get exit value

Tags: bash, variables, stdout, capture, stderr

I need to capture the output and error of a command in my bash script and know whether the command succeeded or not.

At the moment, I am capturing both like this:

```
output=$(mycommand 2>&1)
```

I then need to check the exit value of mycommand. If it failed, I need to do some stuff with the output, if the command succeeded, I don't need to touch the output.

Since I am capturing the output, checking $? is always a 0 since bash succeeded at capturing the output into the variable.

This is a very time sensitive script, so we are trying to avoid any slower solutions like outputting to a file and re-reading it in.

If I could capture stdout to one variable and stderr to another, that would solve my problem because I could just check if the error variable was empty or not.

Thanks.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/002](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002) and [BashFAQ/047](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What version of `bash` are you using? The capture of the output has *zero* effect on the return code with my version, `4.1.5`:

```
pax> false; echo $?
1
pax> echo $?
0
pax> x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?
1
```

It's not always a good idea to rely on standard error being non-empty to detect errors. Many programs don't output errors but rely *solely* on the return code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I pipe the output of my command to another. Although I can do that after wards in a separate command. Thanks.

Comment: Caution! Having `local x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?` or `set x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?` (note **`local/set`** at the begining) outputs `0` not `1` as the last command run is `local/set`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem only seems to manifest when the output is captured to a *local* variable within a function:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.48(1)-release
$ false; echo $?
1
$ echo $?
0
$ x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?
1
$ function f {
> local x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?
> }
$ f
0
$ function g {
> x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?
> }
$ g
1
```

Notice that only function f, which captures x to a local, can express the behavior.  Particularly, function g which does the same thing, but without the 'local' keyword, works.

One can therefore not use a local variable, and perhaps 'unset' it after use.

**EDIT** NVRAM points out that the local declaration can be made beforehand to avoid the issue:

```
$ function h {
>   local x
>   x=$(false 2>&1) ; echo $?
> }
$ h
1
```

Comment: Very interesting! This happens in bash as well as dash (posix) shell.

Comment: Actually $? is set for the local variable declaration, if you simply declare it by itself, _then_ assign it on a separate line it will work as you want. In other words, add **local x** above your line with **x=**