# AppleScript Runner exit status passed back to shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, applescript, osascript

I need to be able to run AppleScript in a shell script. I am using "AppleScript Runner" in order to be in interactive mode, so that dialogs etc. are supported. I've got it working, but I need to get the exit status of the AppleScript Runner app back to the shell, so I can see if there were any errors in the script.

Here is my shell script:

```
output=$(/usr/bin/osascript << EOT
tell application "AppleScript Runner"
do script "somescript.scpt"
end
EOT)

status=$?
```

Here my variable $status only ends up with the exit status of the osascript command (which will be 0 whether or not somescript.scpt actually ran successfully), and not the exit status of the app AppleScript Runner.

Does any one know how I might accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The -e flag prints errors to stderr and is the default.  So you just need to read stderr.

This answer might help you if you aren't familiar with that:

[bash variable capture stderr and stdout separately or get exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632603/bash-variable-capture-stderr-and-stdout-separately-or-get-exit-value)

EDIT: Added sample code.

```
error=`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to adtivate' 2>&1`
echo $error
```

The above on my system captures the error messages.

Comment: I seem to be only getting the error messages in stdout and not stderr with this setup. I have used "set -e" in my shell script as well.

Comment: I just tested a short script on my system and it's going to stderr.