# Capture stdout and stderr into different variables

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, io-redirection

Is it possible to store or capture stdout and stderr in *different variables*, without using a temp file?  Right now I do this to get stdout in `out` and stderr in `err` when running `some_command`, but I'd
like to avoid the temp file.

```
error_file=$(mktemp)
out=$(some_command 2>$error_file)
err=$(< $error_file)
rm $error_file
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632603/bash-variable-capture-stderr-and-stdout-separately-or-get-exit-value) includes my question, but does not answer it.

Comment: fwiw, it's possible in ksh93. `ksh -c 'function f { echo out; echo err >&2; }; x=${ { y=$(f); } 2>&1;}; typeset -p x y'`

Comment: @ormaaj: can you explain how the ksh93 technique works?  You might need make it an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [capture both stdout and stderr in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806626/capture-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Well, that question is posterior to this one, so, if there is a duplicate, it should be that one: [capture both stdout and stderr in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806626/capture-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash):-D

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Ok, it got a bit ugly, but here is a solution:

```bash
unset t_std t_err
eval "$( (echo std; echo err >&2) \
        2> >(readarray -t t_err; typeset -p t_err) \
         > >(readarray -t t_std; typeset -p t_std) )"
```

where `(echo std; echo err >&2)` needs to be replaced by the actual command. Output of *stdout* is saved into the array `$t_std` line by line omitting the newlines (the `-t`) and *stderr* into `$t_err`.

If you don't like arrays you can do

```bash
unset t_std t_err
eval "$( (echo std; echo err >&2 ) \
        2> >(t_err=$(cat); typeset -p t_err) \
         > >(t_std=$(cat); typeset -p t_std) )"
```

which pretty much mimics the behavior of `var=$(cmd)` except for the value of `$?` which takes us to the last modification:

```bash
unset t_std t_err t_ret
eval "$( (echo std; echo err >&2; exit 2 ) \
        2> >(t_err=$(cat); typeset -p t_err) \
         > >(t_std=$(cat); typeset -p t_std); t_ret=$?; typeset -p t_ret )"
```

Here `$?` is preserved into `$t_ret`

Tested on Debian wheezy using *GNU* `bash`, Version *4.2.37(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)*.

Comment: Good work! I tried to abstract your answer into a shell function, but its behaviour confuses me: `eval "eval \"\$@\" 2> >($err=\$(cat); typeset -p $err) 1> >($out=\$(cat); typeset -p $out) ; \\echo \(exit \$?\)"` results in the printing happening in *opposite* the expected order, i.e. it produces `(exit <exit code>);
declare -- <out variable>=<std out>;
declare -- <err variable>=<std err>` ???

Comment: That is why I would handle return the same way. Try `eval "$( eval "$@" 2> >(t_err=$(cat); typeset -p t_err) > >(t_std=$(cat); typeset -p t_std); t_ret=$?; typeset -p t_ret )"; exit $t_ret`

Comment: Thanks for the concept. I have expanded (distilled) it a bit in here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28796214/2350426

Comment: `typeset -p t_out` and `typeset -p t_err` might be mixed, rending the output useless.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I thought about that possibility but could not confirm that this can happen.

Comment: @TheConstructor Hmm, I think you are right. I was in Zsh and was using `>>()` instead of `> >()`. The former is a no-go in Bash; in Zsh it correctly parses out the process substitution part, but sometimes emits mangled output. Not sure why, but `> >()` seems to work reliably. I'm still not totally convinced though. `typeset -p` is definitely not atomic, is it?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Sorry It had to be in all caps, I was searching for this answer so long!

Comment: Can the final version be wrapped in a function like `eval-unpacked "echo std; echo err >&2; exit 2" t_stdout t_stderr t_ret`?

Comment: I managed to turn it into a function but it only works in ZSH: https://gist.github.com/cmcdragonkai/9d1589256053d24dd8d2ce163147c6b8

Comment: If the script I try to capture the output of contains starting a PostgreSQL cluster (`/usr/bin/pg_createcluster --start`), the base script (which contains the capturing call) never gets past `eval`. The command after `eval` never runs and the script does not exit either, it just stops (waiting on someting?). Do you have any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: I am not used to that command. Could it be asking for a password?

Comment: My understanding of shell/bash is not very good. So I didn't understand these points... 
 > `unset` -> Why use `unset`? 
 > `variable=$(cat)` -> What does this construct with `cat` do? 
 > `typeset -p variable` -> What does this construct with `typeset -p` do? 
 > `variable=$?` -> What does `$?` do? 
**Could someone explain?** 

Comment: @EduardoLucio `unset` ensures that previous assignments to the variables are cleared (probably unneeded). `$(cat)` basically allows me to capture the current input stream (as selected through `> >(` / `2> >(`) by reading it and outputting it again; could I just assign a stream to a variable, I would do that instead. `typeset -p` outputs the definition of a variable in a format that can be used to recreate the variable with its value using `eval`. `$?` is the exit-code of the previous command.

Answer (score 79):

I think before saying “you can't” do something, people should at least give it a try with their own hands…

## Simple and clean solution, without using `eval` or anything exotic

### 1. A minimal version

```bash
{
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
} < <((printf '\0%s\0' "$(some_command)" 1>&2) 2>&1)
```

**Requires:** `printf`, `read`

### 2. A simple test

#### A dummy script for producing `stdout` and `stderr`: `useless.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# useless.sh
#

echo "This is stderr" 1>&2
echo "This is stdout"
```

#### The actual script that will capture `stdout` and `stderr`: `capture.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# capture.sh
#

{
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
} < <((printf '\0%s\0' "$(./useless.sh)" 1>&2) 2>&1)

echo 'Here is the captured stdout:'
echo "${CAPTURED_STDOUT}"
echo

echo 'And here is the captured stderr:'
echo "${CAPTURED_STDERR}"
echo
```

#### Output of `capture.sh`

```
Here is the captured stdout:
This is stdout

And here is the captured stderr:
This is stderr
```

### 3. How it works

The command

```bash
(printf '\0%s\0' "$(some_command)" 1>&2) 2>&1
```

sends the standard output of `some_command` to `printf '\0%s\0'`, thus creating the string `\0${stdout}\n\0` (where `\0` is a `NUL` byte and `\n` is a new line character); the string `\0${stdout}\n\0` is then redirected to the standard error, where the standard error of `some_command` was already present, thus composing the string `${stderr}\n\0${stdout}\n\0`, which is then redirected back to the standard output.

Afterwards, the command

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
```

starts reading the string `${stderr}\n\0${stdout}\n\0` up until the first `NUL` byte and saves the content into `${CAPTURED_STDERR}`. Then the command

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
```

keeps reading the same string up to the next `NUL` byte and saves the content into `${CAPTURED_STDOUT}`.

### 4. Making it unbreakable

The solution above relies on a `NUL` byte for the delimiter between `stderr` and `stdout`, therefore it will not work if for any reason `stderr` contains other `NUL` bytes.

Although that will rarely happen, it is possible to make the script completely unbreakable by stripping all possible `NUL` bytes from `stdout` and `stderr` before passing both outputs to `read` (sanitization) – `NUL` bytes would anyway get lost, as [it is not possible to store them into shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash/24511770#24511770):

```bash
{
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
} < <((printf '\0%s\0' "$((some_command | tr -d '\0') 3>&1- 1>&2- 2>&3- | tr -d '\0')" 1>&2) 2>&1)
```

**Requires:** `printf`, `read`, `tr`

### 5. Preserving the exit status – the blueprint (without sanitization)

After thinking a bit about the ultimate approach, I have come out with a solution that uses `printf` to cache *both* `stdout` and the exit code as two different arguments, so that they never interfere.

The first thing I did was outlining a way to communicate the exit status to the third argument of `printf`, and this was something very easy to do in its simplest form (i.e. without sanitization).

```bash
{
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
    (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; exit ${_ERRNO_});
} < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(some_command)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
```

**Requires:** `exit`, `printf`, `read`

### 6. Preserving the exit status with sanitization – unbreakable (rewritten)

Things get very messy though when we try to introduce sanitization. Launching `tr` for sanitizing the streams does in fact overwrite our previous exit status, so apparently the only solution is to redirect the latter to a separate descriptor before it gets lost, keep it there until `tr` does its job twice, and then redirect it back to its place.

After some quite acrobatic redirections between file descriptors, this is what I came out with.

The code below is a rewrite of a previous example (you can find it in the appendix below). It also sanitizes possible `NUL` bytes in the streams, so that `read` can always work properly.

```bash
{
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
    (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; exit ${_ERRNO_});
} < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(((({ some_command; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)") 4>&1-)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
```

**Requires:** `exit`, `printf`, `read`, `tr`

This solution is really robust. The exit code is always kept separated in a different descriptor until it reaches `printf` directly as a separate argument.

### 7. The ultimate solution – a general purpose function with exit status

We can also transform the code above to a general purpose function.

```bash
# SYNTAX:
#   catch STDOUT_VARIABLE STDERR_VARIABLE COMMAND [ARG1[ ARG2[ ...[ ARGN]]]]
catch() {
    {
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${1}";
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${2}";
        (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; return ${_ERRNO_});
    } < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(((({ shift 2; "${@}"; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)") 4>&1-)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
}
```

**Requires:** `cat`, `exit`, `printf`, `read`, `shift`, `tr`

**ChangeLog**: 2022-06-17 // Replaced `${3}` with `shift 2; ${@}` after [**Pavel Tankov**'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/capture-stdout-and-stderr-into-different-variables/59592881?noredirect=1#comment126850672_59592881) (Bash-only). 2023-01-18 // Replaced `${@}` with `"${@}"` after [**cbugk**'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/capture-stdout-and-stderr-into-different-variables/59592881?noredirect=1#comment131497771_59592881).

With the `catch` function we can launch the following snippet,

```bash
catch MY_STDOUT MY_STDERR './useless.sh'

echo "The \`./useless.sh\` program exited with code ${?}"
echo

echo 'Here is the captured stdout:'
echo "${MY_STDOUT}"
echo

echo 'And here is the captured stderr:'
echo "${MY_STDERR}"
echo
```

and get the following result:

```
The `./useless.sh` program exited with code 0

Here is the captured stdout:
This is stderr 1
This is stderr 2

And here is the captured stderr:
This is stdout 1
This is stdout 2
```

### 8. What happens in the last examples

Here follows a fast schematization:

1. `some_command` is launched: we then have `some_command`'s `stdout` on the descriptor 1, `some_command`'s `stderr` on the descriptor 2 and `some_command`'s exit code redirected to the descriptor 3
2. `stdout` is piped to `tr` (sanitization)
3. `stderr` is swapped with `stdout` (using temporarily the descriptor 4) and piped to `tr` (sanitization)
4. the exit code (descriptor 3) is swapped with `stderr` (now descriptor 1) and piped to `exit $(cat)`
5. `stderr` (now descriptor 3) is redirected to the descriptor 1, end expanded as the second argument of `printf`
6. the exit code of `exit $(cat)` is captured by the third argument of `printf`
7. the output of `printf` is redirected to the descriptor 2, where `stdout` was already present
8. the concatenation of `stdout` and the output of `printf` is piped to `read`

### 9. The POSIX-compliant version #1 (breakable)

[Process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) (the `< <()` syntax) are not POSIX-standard (although they *de facto* are). In a shell that does not support the `< <()` syntax the only way to reach the same result is via the `<<EOF … EOF` syntax. Unfortunately this does not allow us to use `NUL` bytes as delimiters, because these get automatically stripped out before reaching `read`. We must use a different delimiter. The natural choice falls onto the `CTRL+Z` character (ASCII character no. 26). Here is a *breakable* version (outputs must never contain the `CTRL+Z` character, or otherwise they will get mixed).

```bash
_CTRL_Z_=$'\cZ'

{
    IFS=$'\n'"${_CTRL_Z_}" read -r -d "${_CTRL_Z_}" CAPTURED_STDERR;
    IFS=$'\n'"${_CTRL_Z_}" read -r -d "${_CTRL_Z_}" CAPTURED_STDOUT;
    (IFS=$'\n'"${_CTRL_Z_}" read -r -d "${_CTRL_Z_}" _ERRNO_; exit ${_ERRNO_});
} <<EOF
$((printf "${_CTRL_Z_}%s${_CTRL_Z_}%d${_CTRL_Z_}" "$(some_command)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
EOF
```

**Requires:** `exit`, `printf`, `read`

**Note:** As `shift` is Bash-only, in this POSIX-compliant version command + arguments must appear under the same quotes.

### 10. The POSIX-compliant version #2 (unbreakable, but not as good as the non-POSIX one)

And here is its unbreakable version, directly in function form (if either `stdout` or `stderr` contain `CTRL+Z` characters, the stream will be truncated, but will never be exchanged with another descriptor).

```bash
_CTRL_Z_=$'\cZ'

# SYNTAX:
#     catch_posix STDOUT_VARIABLE STDERR_VARIABLE COMMAND
catch_posix() {
    {
        IFS=$'\n'"${_CTRL_Z_}" read -r -d "${_CTRL_Z_}" "${1}";
        IFS=$'\n'"${_CTRL_Z_}" read -r -d "${_CTRL_Z_}" "${2}";
        (IFS=$'\n'"${_CTRL_Z_}" read -r -d "${_CTRL_Z_}" _ERRNO_; return ${_ERRNO_});
    } <<EOF
$((printf "${_CTRL_Z_}%s${_CTRL_Z_}%d${_CTRL_Z_}" "$(((({ ${3}; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | cut -z -d"${_CTRL_Z_}" -f1 | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | cut -z -d"${_CTRL_Z_}" -f1 | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)") 4>&1-)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
EOF
}
```

**Requires:** `cat`, `cut`, `exit`, `printf`, `read`, `tr`

### Answer's history

Here is a previous version of `catch()` before **Pavel Tankov**'s comment (this version requires the additional arguments to be quoted together with the command):

> ```bash
> # SYNTAX:
> #  catch STDOUT_VARIABLE STDERR_VARIABLE COMMAND [ARG1[ ARG2[ ...[ ARGN]]]]
> catch() {
>   {
>       IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${1}";
>       IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${2}";
>       (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; return ${_ERRNO_});
>   } < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(((({ shift 2; ${@}; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)") 4>&1-)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
> }
> ```
>
> **Requires:** `cat`, `exit`, `printf`, `read`, `tr`

Furthermore, I replaced an old example for propagating the exit status to the current shell, because, as **Andy** had pointed out in the comments, it was not as “unbreakable” as it was supposed to be (since it did not use `printf` to buffer one of the streams). For the record I paste the problematic code here:

> ### Preserving the exit status (still unbreakable)
>
> The following variant propagates also the exit status of `some_command` to the current shell:
>
> ```bash
> {
>   IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
>   IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
>   (IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_EXIT; exit "${CAPTURED_EXIT}");
> } < <((({ { some_command ; echo "${?}" 1>&3; } | tr -d '\0'; printf '\0'; } 2>&1- 1>&4- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | xargs printf '\0%s\0' 1>&4-) 4>&1-)
> ```
>
> **Requires:** `printf`, `read`, `tr`, `xargs`

Later, **Andy** submitted the following “suggested edit” for capturing the exit code:

> ### Simple and clean solution saving the exit value
>
> We can add to the end of `stderr`, a third piece of information, another `NUL` plus the `exit` status of the command. It will be outputted after `stderr` but before `stdout`
>
> ```bash
> {
>   IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
>   IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_EXIT;
>   IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
> } < <((printf '\0%s\n\0' "$(some_command; printf '\0%d' "${?}" 1>&2)" 1>&2) 2>&1)
> ```

His solution seemed to work, but had the minor problem that the exit status needed to be placed as the last fragment of the string, so that we are able to launch `exit "${CAPTURED_EXIT}"` within round brackets and not pollute the global scope, as I had tried to do in the removed example. The other problem was that, as the output of his innermost `printf` got immediately appended to the `stderr` of `some_command`, we could no more sanitize possible `NUL` bytes in `stderr`, because among these now there was also *our* `NUL` delimiter.

Trying to find the right solution to this problem was what led me to write **§ 5. Preserving the exit status – the blueprint (without sanitization)**, and the following sections.

Comment: The last version does not work correctly. Try command `find /proc` as non root. The previous versions work wonderfully because you are using printf's argument to "buffer" stdout, guaranteeing that stdout is not printed until after the command is complete and 100% of stderr is streamed and flushed. However, the last version is not using printf to buffed one of the streams, only the exit code. Stderr and stdout are interleaved, and stderr only contains one flush's worth. If you fix, an explanation would be much appreciated, as I get lost after FD 4 is introduced

Comment: Hi Andy! Thanks for your comments and edit suggestion. What is the output of `capture.sh` on your machine after patching it with the third version?

Comment: Ok I see it now. The last version truncates `stderr`, right?

Comment: Yes. The result of the last version is that `CAPTURED_STDOUT` has `stdout` _and_ most of `stderr` in it, and `CAPTURED_STDERR` only has the last bit of `stderr` (truncated, as you say). Without using `printf` to "buffer" one of the streams, you have no way to guarantee it is delayed until after the other stream is done streaming.

Comment: Good point. Your solution works, but has the minor problem that the exit status should represent the last piece of the string, if we want to be able to do `exit "${CAPTURED_EXIT}"` within round brackets for not polluting the global scope, as I have tried to do in my last example. The other problem is that, since the output of your innermost `printf` gets immediately appended to the `stderr` of `some_command`, we can no more sanitize possible `NUL` bytes in `stderr`, since among these there is also *our* `NUL` delimiter. I will think about something in the next days.

Comment: Yes, my solution is only a stepping stone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206460/discussion-between-andy-and-madmurphy).

Comment: If the script I try to capture the output of contains starting a PostgreSQL cluster (`/usr/bin/pg_createcluster --start`), the base script (which contains the capturing call) never gets past `catch`. The command after `catch` never runs and the script does not exit either, it just stops (waiting on someting?). Do you have any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: This is genius... Awesome work... Just to clarify, is it correct that all `\0` bytes are completely removed from every stream with the final solution via `tr`?

Comment: @Angel Thank you for your words. I assume you are talking about paragraphs #6 and #7; yes, if you don't remove all `\0` bytes via `tr` they will be anyway removed as soon as you try to store the strings into shell variables. Shell variables cannot contain NUL bytes.

Comment: @JānisElmeris No idea. I am sorry.

Comment: @madmurphy OK. For reference, what I found to work at the time, was the `catch` function of Tino's post (maybe your `catch` would work as well, I don't remember if I tried) to capture, but the script containing the PostgreSQL service starter had to be called like this `{ { command | tee -a $LOG;} 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3- | tee -a $LOG;} 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3-`, which is ugly and loses the exit status for that script/command, but that's the best I could manage.

Comment: While your initial solution is indeed a realtively simple, clean one, it gets very complex, as it evolves into and 'ultimate' solution. Admittedly, I couldn't come up with something like this. That said, I don't think, many people would be able to understand, i. e., maintain code based on your final solution, even after a short time, without re-iterating everything from scratch. So, while maybe technically excellent, I'd rather not use such a construct, which arguably isn't any simpler than the above and probably also has some notable performance impacts. Educationally great, though!

Comment: @fozzybear You should use the solution that works best for you. I felt it was important to give choice and include an unbreakable solution. The latter can still be improved, although with a little bit more effort (it is complex to decipher).

Comment: I think for variant 7. "The ultimate solution – a general purpose function with exit status", you can modify the line like that:
`< <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(((({ shift 2; $@; echo "$?" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit $(cat)) 4>&1-)" "$?" 1>&2) 2>&1)`
i.e. adding a `shift 2` and then using `$@` instead of `$3` so that when calling the function you don't have to enclose the command in quotes:
`catch MY_STDOUT MY_STDERR ls fdasdf` - this is more convenient than 
`catch MY_STDOUT MY_STDERR "ls fdasdf"`

Comment: `read -d` is not POSIX compliant (for variant 9 & 10), also `$((` breaks in some shells, `$( (` is safer

Comment: For 8th, I had to quote `${@}` as `"${@}"` to have `_ERRNO_` as integer. Otherwise `_ERRNO_` was set as `' 1>&4- ) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '`. For context, this was while running `catch VAR_STDOUT VAR_STDERR chroot "${some_path}" /bin/bash -c "${command}"`, where `${command}` is a multiline script as string.

Comment: I could not understand how markdown worked for comments.  I removed a previous comment and posted it instead as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75767120/20130693).

Comment: Hello @madmurphy Thank you for detailed solution. I have a bash script which invokes a "program" and I want to read the messages from the invoked "program" (from stdout) in the script. Will your solution "7. The ultimate solution – a general purpose function with exit status" work in this case?

Comment: @Preeti If you only need to read the standard output (without stderr) you must simply do `MY_OUTPUT="$(program)"`. If instead you need to store both stdout and stderr, then yes, solution #7 was written for that.

Comment: Hello @madmurphy, thank you. Yes I would like to store both stdout and stderr. But, I have some issue storing it. My `COMMAND` is a program which internally executes system reboot and hence the stdout is not caught by the solution #7. Is there any way to capture stdout in this case?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution.
At the end of #7, it appears that your example output is flipped.

`Here is the captured stdout:
This is stderr 1`

Comment: I am speechless, you really went above and beyond with your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Preeti what about using usual `1>out.txt  2>err.txt` assuming you can't place reboot trigger out of the program? You can read output files after system boot, account for your process ending up forcefully terminated though.

Answer (score 32):

> This is for catching stdout and stderr in different variables.  [If you only want to catch `stderr`, leaving `stdout` as-is, there is a better and shorter solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56577569/490291).

To [sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086548/490291) everything [up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26827443/490291) for the benefit of the reader, here is an

## Easy Reusable `bash` Solution

This version does use subshells and runs without `tempfile`s.  (For a `tempfile` version which runs without subshells, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41652679).)

```
: catch STDOUT STDERR cmd args..
catch()
{
eval "$({
__2="$(
  { __1="$("${@:3}")"; } 2>&1;
  ret=$?;
  printf '%q=%q\n' "$1" "$__1" >&2;
  exit $ret
  )";
ret="$?";
printf '%s=%q\n' "$2" "$__2" >&2;
printf '( exit %q )' "$ret" >&2;
} 2>&1 )";
}
```

Example use:

```
dummy()
{
echo "$3" >&2
echo "$2" >&1
return "$1"
}

catch stdout stderr dummy 3 $'\ndiffcult\n data \n\n\n' $'\nother\n difficult \n  data  \n\n'

printf 'ret=%q\n' "$?"
printf 'stdout=%q\n' "$stdout"
printf 'stderr=%q\n' "$stderr"
```

this prints

```
ret=3
stdout=$'\ndiffcult\n data '
stderr=$'\nother\n difficult \n  data  '
```

So it can be used without deeper thinking about it.  Just put `catch VAR1 VAR2` in front of any `command args..` and you are done.

Some `if cmd args..; then` will become `if catch VAR1 VAR2 cmd args..; then`.  Really nothing complex.

### Addendum: Use in "[strict mode](https://github.com/tests-always-included/wick/blob/master/doc/bash-strict-mode.md)"

`catch` works for me identically in strict mode.  The only caveat is, that the example above returns error code 3, which, in strict mode, calls the ERR trap.  Hence if you run some command under `set -e` which is expected to return arbitrary error codes (not only 0), you need to catch the return code into some variable like  `&& ret=$? || ret=$?` as shown below:

```
dummy()
{
echo "$3" >&2
echo "$2" >&1
return "$1"
}

catch stdout stderr dummy 3 $'\ndifficult\n data \n\n\n' $'\nother\n difficult \n  data  \n\n' && ret=$? || ret=$?

printf 'ret=%q\n' "$ret"
printf 'stdout=%q\n' "$stdout"
printf 'stderr=%q\n' "$stderr"
```

### Discussion

Q: How does it work?

It just wraps ideas from the other answers here into a function, such that it can easily be resused.

`catch()` basically uses `eval` to set the two variables.  This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086548

Consider a call of `catch out err dummy 1 2a 3b`:

- let's skip the `eval "$({` and the `__2="$(` for now.  I will come to this later.
- `__1="$("$("${@:3}")"; } 2>&1;` executes `dummy 1 2a 3b` and stores its `stdout` into `__1` for later use.  So `__1` becomes `2a`.  It also redirects `stderr` of `dummy` to `stdout`, such that the outer catch can gather `stdout`
- `ret=$?;` catches the exit code, which is `1`
- `printf '%q=%q\n' "$1" "$__1" >&2;` then outputs `out=2a` to `stderr`.  `stderr` is used here, as the current `stdout` already has taken over the role of `stderr` of the `dummy` command.
- `exit $ret` then forwards the exit code (`1`) to the next stage.

Now to the outer `__2="$( ... )"`:

- This catches `stdout` of the above, which is the `stderr` of the `dummy` call, into variable `__2`.  (We could re-use `__1` here, but I used `__2` to make it less confusing.).  So `__2` becomes `3b`
- `ret="$?";` catches the (returned) return code `1` (from `dummy`) again
- `printf '%s=%q\n' "$2" "$__2" >&2;` then outputs `err=3a` to `stderr`.  `stderr` is used again, as it already was used to output the other variable `out=2a`.
- `printf '( exit %q )' "$ret" >&2;` then outputs the code to set the proper return value.  I did not find a better way, as assigning it to a variable needs a variable name, which then cannot be used as first or second argument to `catch`.

Please note that, as an optimization, we could have written those 2 `printf` as a single one like `printf '%s=%q\n( exit %q )` "$__2" "$ret"` as well.

So what do we have so far?

We have following written to stderr:

```
out=2a
err=3b
( exit 1 )
```

where `out` is from `$1`, `2a` is from `stdout` of `dummy`, `err` is from `$2`, `3b` is from `stderr` of `dummy`, and the `1` is from the return code from `dummy`.

Please note that `%q` in the format of `printf` takes care for quoting, such that the shell sees proper (single) arguments when it comes to `eval`.  `2a` and `3b` are so simple, that they are copied literally.

Now to the outer `eval "$({ ... } 2>&1 )";`:

This executes all of above which output the 2 variables and the `exit`, catches it (therefor the `2>&1`) and parses it into the current shell using `eval`.

This way the 2 variables get set and the return code as well.

Q: It uses `eval` which is evil.  So is it safe?

- As long as `printf %q` has no bugs, it should be safe.  But you always have to be very careful, just think about ShellShock.

Q: Bugs?

- No obvious bugs are known, except following:

  - Catching big output needs big memory and CPU, as everything goes into variables and needs to be back-parsed by the shell.  So use it wisely.
  - As usual `$(echo $'\n\n\n\n')` **swallows all linefeeds**, not only the last one.  This is a POSIX requirement.  If you need to get the LFs unharmed, just add some trailing character to the output and remove it afterwards like in following recipe (look at the trailing `x` which allows to read a softlink pointing to a file which ends on a `$'\n'`):

    ```
        target="$(readlink -e "$file")x"
        target="${target%x}"
    ```
  - Shell-variables cannot carry the byte NUL (`$'\0'`).  They are simply ignores if they happen to occur in `stdout` or `stderr`.
- The given command runs in a sub-subshell.  So it has no access to `$PPID`, nor can it alter shell variables.  You can `catch` a shell function, even builtins, but those will not be able to alter shell variables (as everything running within `$( .. )` cannot do this).  So if you need to run a function in current shell and catch it's stderr/stdout, you need to do this the usual way with `tempfile`s.  (There are ways to do this such, that interrupting the shell normally does not leave debris behind, but this is complex and deserves it's own answer.)

Q: Bash version?

- I think you need Bash 4 and above (due to `printf %q`)

Q: This still looks so awkward.

- Right.  [Another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172617/490291) shows how it can be done in `ksh` much more cleanly.  However I am not used to `ksh`, so I leave it to others to create a similar easy to reuse recipe for `ksh`.

Q: Why not use `ksh` then?

- Because this is a `bash` solution

Q: The script can be improved

- Of course you can squeeze out some bytes and create smaller or more incomprehensible solution.  Just go for it ;)

Q: There is a typo.  `: catch STDOUT STDERR cmd args..` shall read `# catch STDOUT STDERR cmd args..`

- Actually this is intended.  `:` shows up in `bash -x` while comments are silently swallowed.  So you can see where the parser is if you happen to have a typo in the function definition. It's an old debugging trick.  But beware a bit, you can easily create some neat sideffects within the arguments of `:`.

Edit: Added a couple more `;` to make it more easy to create a single-liner out of `catch()`.  And added section how it works.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution considering that it makes such usage much more easier to use. You should however provide a little more details on how it works, considering that it does not follow the general pattern of other proposed solutions.

Comment: How about doing this `catch` for commands that redirect one of the streams or are piping? It might seem questionable to try to capture both outputs is one of them is empty (since the command itself redirects it anyway). But it makes it easier to use same pattern over and over again with any command (especially if the command is externally provided and you don't know whether it redirects) even if in some cases one of the variables is doomed to be empty.

Comment: So far I found a simple workaround. Just define a simple function like `function echo_to_file { echo -n "$1" >"$2" ; }` and then use `catch` with that function. Works as expected. But still it would be nice to have it in `catch` itself. (Similar "trick" can be done to have pipes in the command.)

Comment: @AdamBadura the question was to catch 2 different variables in parallel. If you only want to capture one single variable, you do not need this `catch` here! Single variable capturing is built right into the shell: stdout+stderr: `var="$(command 2>&1)"; echo "command gives $? and outputs '$var'"`; catch stderr and redirect stdout: `var="$(command 2>&1 >FILE)"` (not `>FILE 2>&1`, this would redirect stderr to `FILE`!); stdout-only: `var="$(command)"; echo "command gives $? and has stdout '$var'"`, and [for `stderr` or other FDs see another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56577569/490291)

Comment: In function `catch`, shouldn't the final printf statement be `printf 'return %q\n' "$ret" >&2`?  One wants function `catch` to return `cmd`'s exit code, rather than exiting the program.

Comment: @JimFischer Nice catch, as `eval "return 1"` should return from `catch` as well (sorry for that pun).  A quick test with `bash` worked for me.  So, thanks, this seems to be an improvement and remove an unnecessary fork in the `( exit 1 )`, which creates a subshell which immediately returns with code 1, so it does not exit the current program.  However with the `( exit 1 )` in place this recipe can be dropped outside of functions as well. where `return` does not work.  (Note: `1` is an example here.)

Comment: Can fix it work work with "strict mode", please? It errors at the line `} 2>&1 )";`. I use this definition of strict mode: 
`set -eEu -o pipefail; shopt -s extdebug; IFS=$'\n\t'; trap 'wickStrictModeFail $?' ERR`, available at https://github.com/tests-always-included/wick/blob/master/doc/bash-strict-mode.md

Comment: @Anon21 Thanks for noting "strict mode".  It happens to me that there seems to be no bug in `catch` (YMMV, perhaps there must be `set +e` inside the `eval`).  `catch` is supposed to transparently return the error code of the called command.  In the example `dummy` returns 3.  Hence `set -e` fires the `ERR` trap as it is meant to do!  By catching the error code into a variable in the `catch` invocation, the example also works in "strict mode".  (Edited answer to add this note.)  But note that the `ERR` location perhaps is a bit misleading.  I do not know a good solution for this.  Sorry.

Answer (score 19):

Technically, named pipes aren't temporary files and nobody here mentions them. They store nothing in the filesystem and you can delete them as soon as you connect them (so you won't ever see them):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

foo () {
    echo stdout1
    echo stderr1 >&2
    sleep 1
    echo stdout2
    echo stderr2 >&2
}

rm -f stdout stderr
mkfifo stdout stderr
foo >stdout 2>stderr &             # blocks until reader is connected
exec {fdout}<stdout {fderr}<stderr # unblocks `foo &`
rm stdout stderr                   # filesystem objects are no longer needed

stdout=$(cat <&$fdout)
stderr=$(cat <&$fderr)

echo $stdout
echo $stderr

exec {fdout}<&- {fderr}<&- # free file descriptors, optional
```

You can have multiple background processes this way and asynchronously collect their stdouts and stderrs at a convenient time, etc.

If you need this for one process only, you may just as well use hardcoded fd numbers like 3 and 4, instead of the `{fdout}/{fderr}` syntax (which finds a free fd for you).

Comment: You would need to wait for the `foo &` subshell to complete to get it's exit code. For example, `foo >stdout 2>stderr & pid=$!; exec {fdout}<stdout {fderr}<stderr; wait $pid; rc=$?`

Comment: This helped me to finally solve separated handling of git stdout and stderr in combination with dialog prgbox, many thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This command sets both stdout (stdval) and stderr (errval) values in the present running shell:

```
eval "$( execcommand 2> >(setval errval) > >(setval stdval); )"
```

provided this function has been defined:

```
function setval { printf -v "$1" "%s" "$(cat)"; declare -p "$1"; }
```

Change execcommand to the captured command, be it "ls", "cp", "df", etc.

---

All this is based on the idea that we could convert all captured values to a text line with the help of the function setval, then setval is used to capture each value in this structure:

```
execcommand 2> CaptureErr > CaptureOut
```

Convert each capture value to a setval call:

```
execcommand 2> >(setval errval) > >(setval stdval)
```

Wrap everything inside an execute call and echo it:

```
echo "$( execcommand 2> >(setval errval) > >(setval stdval) )"
```

You will get the declare calls that each setval creates:

```
declare -- stdval="I'm std"
declare -- errval="I'm err"
```

To execute that code (and get the vars set) use eval:

```
eval "$( execcommand 2> >(setval errval) > >(setval stdval) )"
```

and finally echo the set vars:

```
echo "std out is : |$stdval| std err is : |$errval|
```

---

It is also possible to include the return (exit) value.
A complete bash script example looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash --

# The only function to declare:
function setval { printf -v "$1" "%s" "$(cat)"; declare -p "$1"; }

# a dummy function with some example values:
function dummy { echo "I'm std"; echo "I'm err" >&2; return 34; }

# Running a command to capture all values
#      change execcommand to dummy or any other command to test.
eval "$( dummy 2> >(setval errval) > >(setval stdval); <<<"$?" setval retval; )"

echo "std out is : |$stdval| std err is : |$errval| return val is : |$retval|"
```

Comment: There is a **race condition** because `declare` does no atomic writes when the whole output is longer than 1008 bytes (Ubuntu 16.04, bash 4.3.46(1)). There is an implicite synchronization between the two `setval` calls for stdout and stderr (the `cat` in the `setval` for stderr cannot finish before the `setval` for stdout has closed stderr).  However there is no synchronization of the `setval retval`, hence it can come anywhere between.  In this case, `retval` is swallowed in one of the two other variables.  So the `retval` case does not run reliably.

Comment: I think I like this approach.. kinda. Is there a way to move that eval to a separate function and pass the command to it? When I try that, it doesn't declare the errval or stdval.

Comment: I made `capturable(){...}` (setval as written) and `capture(){ eval "$( $@ 2> >(capturable stderr) > >(capturable stdout); )"; test -z "$stderr" }`. `capture make ... && echo "$stdout" || less <<<"$stderr"` pages stderr or prints stdout if there is none. Does this work for you, or help you if it does?

Answer (score 14):

Jonathan has [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027843/495451). For reference, this is the ksh93 trick. (requires a non-ancient version).

```
function out {
    echo stdout
    echo stderr >&2
}

x=${ { y=$(out); } 2>&1; }
typeset -p x y # Show the values
```

produces

```
x=stderr
y=stdout
```

The `${ cmds;}` syntax is just a command substitution that doesn't create a subshell. The commands are executed in the current shell environment. The space at the beginning is important (`{` is a reserved word).

Stderr of the inner command group is redirected to stdout (so that it applies to the inner substitution). Next, the stdout of `out` is assigned to `y`, and the redirected stderr is captured by `x`, without the usual loss of `y` to a command substitution's subshell.

It isn't possible in other shells, because all constructs which capture output require putting the producer into a subshell, which in this case, would include the assignment.

*update:* Now also supported by mksh.

Comment: Thanks.  The key point is that `${ ... }` is not a sub-shell, which leaves the rest readily explicable.  Neat trick, as long as you've got a `ksh` to use.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question is about the bash, whereas your answer is valid on ksh.

Comment: @mshamma Obviously. Read the last paragraph.

Answer (score 11):

This is a diagram showing how @madmurphy's [very neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592881/1388292) works.

[image: Diagram of @madmurhy's solution]

And an indented version of the one-liner:

```
catch() {
  {
      IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "$out_var";
      IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "$err_var";
      (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; return ${_ERRNO_});
  }\
  < <(
    (printf '\0%s\0%d\0' \
      "$(
        (
          (
            (
              { ${3}; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-
            ) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-
          ) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)"
        ) 4>&1-
      )" "${?}" 1>&2
    ) 2>&1
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice diagram, Jacques. I'm having a little trouble following your intent of the meaning of each of the horizontal lines. I originally assumed each horizontal line was a file descriptor but that's obviously not the case. Maybe you could add some axes labels and a legend?

Answer (score 5):

Did not like the eval, so here is a solution that uses some redirection tricks to capture program output to a variable and then parses that variable to extract the different components. The -w flag sets the chunk size and influences the ordering of std-out/err messages in the intermediate format. 1 gives potentially high resolution at the cost of overhead.

```
#######                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# runs "$@" and outputs both stdout and stderr on stdin, both in a prefixed format allowing both std in and out to be separately stored in variables later.                                                                  
# limitations: Bash does not allow null to be returned from subshells, limiting the usefullness of applying this function to commands with null in the output.                                                                   
# example:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#  var=$(keepBoth ls . notHere)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#  echo ls had the exit code "$(extractOne r "$var")"                                                                                                                                                                            
#  echo ls had the stdErr of "$(extractOne e "$var")"                                                                                                                                                                            
#  echo ls had the stdOut of "$(extractOne o "$var")"                                                                                                                                                                            
keepBoth() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  (                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    prefix(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      ( set -o pipefail                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        base64 -w 1 - | (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          while read c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          do echo -E "$1" "$c"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
          done                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    ( (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        "$@" | prefix o >&3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        echo  ${PIPESTATUS[0]} | prefix r >&3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      ) 2>&1 | prefix e >&1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ) 3>&1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

extractOne() { # extract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  echo "$2" | grep "^$1" | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=2 | base64 --decode -                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of the reader here is a solution using `tempfile`s.

The question was not to use `tempfile`s.  However this might be due to the unwanted pollution of `/tmp/` with tempfile in case the shell dies.  In case of `kill -9` some `trap 'rm "$tmpfile1" "$tmpfile2"' 0` does not fire.

If you are in a situation where you can **use `tempfile`**, but want to **never leave debris behind**, here is a recipe.

Again it is called `catch()` (as my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069638)) and has the same calling syntax:

`catch stdout stderr command args..`

```
# Wrappers to avoid polluting the current shell's environment with variables

: catch_read returncode FD variable
catch_read()
{
eval "$3=\"\`cat <&$2\`\"";
# You can use read instead to skip some fork()s.
# However read stops at the first NUL byte,
# also does no \n removal and needs bash 3 or above:
#IFS='' read -ru$2 -d '' "$3";
return $1;
}
: catch_1 tempfile variable comand args..
catch_1()
{
{
rm -f "$1";
"${@:3}" 66<&-;
catch_read $? 66 "$2";
} 2>&1 >"$1" 66<"$1";
}

: catch stdout stderr command args..
catch()
{
catch_1 "`tempfile`" "${2:-stderr}" catch_1 "`tempfile`" "${1:-stdout}" "${@:3}";
}
```

What it does:

- It creates two `tempfile`s for `stdout` and `stderr`.  However it nearly immediately removes these, such that they are only around for a very short time.
- `catch_1()` catches `stdout` (FD 1) into a variable and moves `stderr` to `stdout`, such that the next ("left") `catch_1` can catch that.
- Processing in `catch` is done from right to left, so the left `catch_1` is executed last and catches `stderr`.

The worst which can happen is, that some temporary files show up on `/tmp/`, but they are always empty in that case.  (They are removed before they get filled.).  Usually this should not be a problem, as under Linux tmpfs supports roughly 128K files per GB of main memory.

- The given command can access and alter all local shell variables as well.  So you can call a shell function which has sideffects!
- This only forks twice for the `tempfile` call.

Bugs:

- Missing good error handling in case `tempfile` fails.
- This does the usual `\n` removal of the shell.  See comment in `catch_read()`.
- You cannot use file descriptor `66` to pipe data to your command.  If you need that, use another descriptor for the redirection, like `42` (note that very old shells only offer FDs up to 9).
- This cannot handle NUL bytes (`$'\0'`) in `stdout` and `stderr`.  (NUL is just ignored.  For the `read` variant everything behind a NUL is ignored.)

FYI:

- Unix allows us to access deleted files, as long as you keep some reference to them around (such as an open filehandle).  This way we can open and then remove them.

Answer (score 3):

In the ***bash realm***, @madmurphy's *"[7. The ultimate solution – a general purpose function with exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592881/19710446)"* is *the* way to go that I've been massively using everywhere. Based on my experience I'm contributing minor updates making it really "ultimate" also in the following two scenarios:

1. complex command lines to have args correctly quoted and without the need of quoting the original commands which are now naturally typed as plain tokens. ( the replacement is this`..."$(((({ "${@:3}" ; echo...`)
2. our trusted friend "debug" options. `xtrace` and `verbose` work by injecting text into `stderr`... You can immagine for how long I was baffled by the erratic behaviour of scripts that seemed to work perfectly well just before the `catch`... And the problem actually was quite subtler and required to take care of `xtrace` and `verbose` options as mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21944

One of my use case scenarios, where you'll get why the entire quoting mechanism was a problem is the following. Also, to detect the length of a video and do something else in case of error, I needed some debug before figuring out how this fast `ffprobe` command fails on the given video:

```
catch end err ffprobe -i "${filename}" -show_entries format=duration -v warning -of csv='p=0'
```

This, in my experience so far, is the *ultimate* **ultimate** ;-) one, and hope may serve you as well. Credits to @madmurphy and all other contributors.

```
catch() {
  if [ "$#" -lt 3 ]; then
     echo USAGE:  catch STDOUT_VAR STDERR_VAR COMMAND [CMD_ARGS...]
     echo 'stdout-> ${STDOUT_VAR}' 'stderr-> ${STDERR_VAR}' 'exit-> ${?}'
     echo -e "\n** NOTICE: FD redirects are used to make the magic happen."
     echo "   Shell's xtrace (set -x) and verbose (set -v) work by redirecting to stderr, which screws the magic up."
     echo "   xtrace (set -x) and verbose (set -v) modes are suspended during the execution of this function."
     return 1
  fi

  # check "verbose" option, turn if off if enabled, and save restore status USE_V
  [[ ${-/v} != $- ]] && set +v && USE_V="-v" || USE_V="+v"
  # check "xtrace" option, turn if off if enabled, and save restore status USE_X
  [[ ${-/x} != $- ]] && set +x && USE_X="-x" || USE_X="+x"
  
    {
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${1}";
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${2}";
        # restore the "xtrace" and "verbose" options before returning
        (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; set $USE_X; set $USE_V; return "${_ERRNO_}");
    } < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(((({ "${@:3}" ; echo "${?}" 1>&3-; } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)") 4>&1-)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Succinctly, I believe the answer is 'No'.  The capturing `$( ... )` only captures standard output to the variable; there isn't a way to get the standard error captured into a separate variable.  So, what you have is about as neat as it gets.

Comment: @ormaaj: By the look of the answers based on `eval`, it seems that it is actually possible, but, as [you point out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/bash-store-stdout-and-stderr-in-different-#answer-11172617), it basically boils down to ‘_use a better shell or language_’. It's not directly an answer to the question, but I came here with the same question and I think that, long-term, I'm going to switch to a shell based on a [functional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) such as [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29).

Answer (score 2):

What about... =D

```
GET_STDERR=""
GET_STDOUT=""
get_stderr_stdout() {
    GET_STDERR=""
    GET_STDOUT=""
    unset t_std t_err
    eval "$( (eval $1) 2> >(t_err=$(cat); typeset -p t_err) > >(t_std=$(cat); typeset -p t_std) )"
    GET_STDERR=$t_err
    GET_STDOUT=$t_std
}

get_stderr_stdout "command"
echo "$GET_STDERR"
echo "$GET_STDOUT"
```

Comment: This appears to be a wrapper around the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18086548/470844) that doesn't add any new functionality. How is this different / more useful?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround, which is hacky but perhaps more intuitive than some of the suggestions on this page, is to tag the output streams, merge them, and split afterwards based on the tags. For example, we might tag stdout with a "STDOUT" prefix:

```
function someCmd {
    echo "I am stdout"
    echo "I am stderr" 1>&2
}

ALL=$({ someCmd | sed -e 's/^/STDOUT/g'; } 2>&1)
OUT=$(echo "$ALL" | grep    "^STDOUT" | sed -e 's/^STDOUT//g')
ERR=$(echo "$ALL" | grep -v "^STDOUT")
```

```

If you know that stdout and/or stderr are of a restricted form, you can come up with a tag which does not conflict with their allowed content.

Comment: Did a more general way to do this that works for all outputs, see my answer to this question.

Comment: Does this risk that `sed` interprets the outut of `someCmd`? Potential unwanted code execution?

Comment: @adrelanos AFAIK in the above examples `sed` will only interpret the string arguments, i.e. `s/^/STDOUT/g` and `s/^STDOUT//g`. Since these are fixed, known strings there is no injection/unwanted execution vector. The stdout and stderr of `someCmd` will flow through the stdin and stdout of `sed`; they will be edited but not executed. Likewise for the calls to `grep`.

Comment: @adrelanos Note that I'm assuming that the stdout and stderr of `someCmd` will never contain a line beginning with the "sentinel" text `STDOUT`. If this doesn't hold we could pick a different sentinel; but if the output is *arbitrary* (e.g. user-defined) then this method cannot be used, since there is no way to distinguish *any* sentinel text from the data.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: NOT (yet?) WORKING!**

The following seems a possible lead to get it working without creating any temp files and also on POSIX sh only; it requires base64 however and due to the encoding/decoding may not be that efficient and use also "larger" memory.

- Even in the simple case, it would already fail, when the last stderr line has no newline. This can be fixed at least in some cases with replacing exe with "{ exe ; echo >&2 ; }", i.e. adding a newline.
- The main problem is however that everything seems racy. Try using an exe like:

  exe()
  {
      cat /usr/share/hunspell/de_DE.dic
      cat /usr/share/hunspell/en_GB.dic >&2
  }

and you'll see that e.g. parts of the base64 encoded line is on the top of the file, parts at the end, and the non-decoded stderr stuff in the middle.

**Well, even if the idea below cannot be made working (which I assume), it may serve as an anti-example for people who may falsely believe it could be made working like this.**

Idea (or anti-example):

```
#!/bin/sh

exe()
{
        echo out1
        echo err1 >&2
        echo out2
        echo out3
        echo err2 >&2
        echo out4
        echo err3 >&2
        echo -n err4 >&2
}


r="$(  { exe  |  base64 -w 0 ; }  2>&1 )"

echo RAW
printf '%s' "$r"
echo RAW

o="$( printf '%s' "$r" | tail -n 1 | base64 -d )"
e="$( printf '%s' "$r" | head -n -1  )"
unset r    

echo
echo OUT
printf '%s' "$o"
echo OUT
echo
echo ERR
printf '%s' "$e"
echo ERR
```

gives (with the stderr-newline fix):

```
$ ./ggg 
RAW
err1
err2
err3
err4

b3V0MQpvdXQyCm91dDMKb3V0NAo=RAW

OUT
out1
out2
out3
out4OUT

ERR
err1
err2
err3
err4ERR
```

(At least on Debian's dash and bash)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an variant of @madmurphy solution that should work for arbitrarily large stdout/stderr streams, maintain the exit return value, and handle nulls in the stream (by converting them to newlines)

```sh
function buffer_plus_null()
{
  local buf
  IFS= read -r -d '' buf || :
  echo -n "${buf}"
  printf '\0'
}

{
    IFS= time read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDOUT;
    IFS= time read -r -d '' CAPTURED_STDERR;
    (IFS= read -r -d '' CAPTURED_EXIT; exit "${CAPTURED_EXIT}");
} < <((({ { some_command ; echo "${?}" 1>&3; } | tr '\0' '\n' | buffer_plus_null; } 2>&1 1>&4 | tr '\0' '\n' | buffer_plus_null 1>&4 ) 3>&1 | xargs printf '%s\0' 1>&4) 4>&1 )
```

Cons:

- The `read` commands are the most expensive part of the operation. For example: `find /proc` on a computer running 500 processes, takes 20 seconds (while the command was only 0.5 seconds). It takes 10 seconds to read in the first time, and 10 seconds more to read the second time, doubling the total time.

---

### Explanation of buffer

The original solution was to an argument to `printf` to buffer the stream, however with the need to have the exit code come last, one solution is to buffer both stdout and stderr. I tried `xargs -0 printf` but then you quickly started hitting "max argument length limits". So I decided a solution was to write a quick buffer function:

1. Use `read` to store the stream in a variable
2. This `read` will terminate when the stream ends, or a null is received. Since we already removed the nulls, it ends when the stream is closed, and returns non-zero. Since this is expected behavior we add `|| :` meaning "or true" so that the line always evaluates to true (0)
3. Now that I know the stream has ended, it's safe to start echoing it back out.
4. `echo -n "${buf}"` is a builtin command and thus not limited to the argument length limit
5. Lastly, add a null separator to the end.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just to clarify, what's the main addition to the original? Does the original option work for relatively large data (i.e. 5,000 kB) or not? It seems it does. Regarding the speed, the original takes 5.8s, the alternative - 9.9s for `declare i; for (( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )); do dmesg; done` code (`5338099` characters).

Answer (score 1):

This prefixes error messages (similar to the answer of @Warbo) and by that we are able to distinguish between stdout and stderr:

```
out=$(some_command 2> >(sed -e 's/^/stderr/g'))
err=$(echo "$out" | grep -oP "(?<=^stderr).*")
out=$(echo "$out" | grep -v '^stderr')
```

The `(?<=string)` part is called a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which excludes the string from the result.

**How I use it**

```
# cat ./script.sh
#!/bin/bash
# check script arguments
args=$(getopt -u -l "foo,bar" "fb" "$@" 2> >(sed -e 's/^/stderr/g') )
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo -n "Error: " && echo "$args" | grep -oP "(?<=^stderr).*" && exit 1
mapfile -t args < <(xargs -n1 <<< "$args")
#
# ./script.sh --foo --bar --baz
# Error: getopt: unrecognized option '--baz'
```

Notes:

- As you can see I don't need to filter for `stdout` as the condition already catched the error and stopped the script. So if the script does not stop, `$args` does not contain any prefixed content.
- An alternative to `sed -e 's/^/stderr/g'` is `xargs -d '\n' -I {} echo "stderr{}"`.

**Variant to prefix stdout AND stderr**

```
# smbclient localhost 1> >(sed -e 's/^/std/g') 2> >(sed -e 's/^/err/g')
std
stdlocalhost: Not enough '\' characters in service
stderrUsage: smbclient [-?EgBVNkPeC] [-?|--help] [--usage]
stderr        [-R|--name-resolve=NAME-RESOLVE-ORDER] [-M|--message=HOST]
stderr        [-I|--ip-address=IP] [-E|--stderr] [-L|--list=HOST]
stderr        [-m|--max-protocol=LEVEL] [-T|--tar=<c|x>IXFqgbNan]
stderr        [-D|--directory=DIR] [-c|--command=STRING] [-b|--send-buffer=BYTES]
stderr        [-t|--timeout=SECONDS] [-p|--port=PORT] [-g|--grepable]
stderr        [-B|--browse] [-d|--debuglevel=DEBUGLEVEL]
stderr        [-s|--configfile=CONFIGFILE] [-l|--log-basename=LOGFILEBASE]
stderr        [-V|--version] [--option=name=value]
stderr        [-O|--socket-options=SOCKETOPTIONS] [-n|--netbiosname=NETBIOSNAME]
stderr        [-W|--workgroup=WORKGROUP] [-i|--scope=SCOPE] [-U|--user=USERNAME]
stderr        [-N|--no-pass] [-k|--kerberos] [-A|--authentication-file=FILE]
stderr        [-S|--signing=on|off|required] [-P|--machine-pass] [-e|--encrypt]
stderr        [-C|--use-ccache] [--pw-nt-hash] service <password>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to Jacques Gaudin's [addendum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70735935/17105430) to madmurphy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59592881/17105430).

Unlike the source, this uses eval to execute multi-line command (multi-argument is ok as well thanks to "${@}").

Another caveat is this function will return 0 in any case, and output exit code to a third variable instead. IMO this is more apt for catch.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Overwrites existing values of provided variables in any case.
# SYNTAX:
#   catch STDOUT_VAR_NAME STDERR_VAR_NAME EXIT_CODE_VAR_NAME COMMAND1 [COMMAND2 [...]]
function catch() {
  {
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${1}";
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${2}";
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "${3}";

    return 0;
  }\
  < <(
    (printf '\0%s\0%d\0' \
      "$(
        (
          (
            (
              {
                shift 3;
                eval "${@}";
                echo "${?}" 1>&3-;
              } | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-
            ) 4>&2- 2>&1- | tr -d '\0' 1>&4-
          ) 3>&1- | exit "$(cat)"
        ) 4>&1-
      )" "${?}" 1>&2
    ) 2>&1
  )
}

# Simulation of here-doc
MULTILINE_SCRIPT_1='cat << EOF
foo
bar
with newlines
EOF
'

# Simulation of multiple streams
# Notice the lack of semi-colons, otherwise below code
# could become a one-liner and still work
MULTILINE_SCRIPT_2='echo stdout stream
echo error stream 1>&2
'

catch out err code "${MULTILINE_SCRIPT_1}" \
                                'printf "wait there is more\n" 1>&2'
printf "1)\n\tSTDOUT: ${out}\n\tSTDERR: ${err}\n\tCODE: ${code}\n"

echo ''

catch out err code "${MULTILINE_SCRIPT_2}" echo this multi-argument \
                                form works too '1>&2' \; \(exit 5\)
printf "2)\n\tSTDOUT: ${out}\n\tSTDERR: ${err}\n\tCODE: ${code}\n"
```

Output:

```
1)
        STDOUT: foo
bar
with newlines
        STDERR: wait there is more
        CODE: 0

2)
        STDOUT: stdout stream
        STDERR: error stream
this multi-argument form works too
        CODE: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If the command 1) no stateful side effects and 2) is computationally cheap, the easiest solution is to just run it twice. I've mainly used this for code that runs during the boot sequence when you don't yet know if the disk is going to be working. In my case it was a tiny `some_command` so there was no performance hit for running twice, and the command had no side effects.

The main benefit is that this is clean and easy to read. The solutions here are quite clever, but I would hate to be the one that has to maintain a script containing the more complicated solutions. I'd recommend the simple run-it-twice approach if your scenario works with that, as it's much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Example:

```
output=$(getopt -o '' -l test: -- "$@")
errout=$(getopt -o '' -l test: -- "$@" 2>&1 >/dev/null)
if [[ -n "$errout" ]]; then
        echo "Option Error: $errout"
fi
```

Again, this is only ok to do because getopt has no side effects. I know it's performance-safe because my parent code calls this less than 100 times during the entire program, and the user will never notice 100 getopt calls vs 200 getopt calls.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm guessing something like `out=$(some_command)` and `err=$(some_command 2>&1 1>/dev/null)`?

Comment: @eicto - then you'll have to use one of the solutions above - this is only a good solution if your command has no side effects and is computationally cheap

Comment: I doubt that there are many use-cases that require separate handling of `stdout` and `stderr` that are free of side-effects – even if a command is deterministic under _normal_ circumstances, errors are not normal circumstances. This approach will also likely be prone to race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler variation that isn't quite what the OP wanted, but is unlike any of the other options. You can get whatever you want by rearranging the file descriptors.

Test command:

```
%> cat xx.sh  
#!/bin/bash
echo stdout
>&2 echo stderr
```

which by itself does:

```
%> ./xx.sh
stdout
stderr
```

Now, print stdout, capture stderr to a variable, & log stdout to a file

```
%> export err=$(./xx.sh 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 >"out")
stdout
%> cat out    
stdout
%> echo
$err 
stderr
```

Or log stdout & capture stderr to a variable:

```
export err=$(./xx.sh 3>&1 1>out 2>&3 )
%> cat out
stdout
%> echo $err
stderr
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime output and write to file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# File where store the output
log_file=/tmp/out.log

# Empty file
echo > ${log_file}

outToLog() {
  # File where write (first parameter)
  local f="$1"
  # Start file output watcher in background
  tail -f "${f}" &
  # Capture background process PID
  local pid=$!
  # Write "stdin" to file
  cat /dev/stdin >> "${f}"
  # Kill background task
  kill -9 ${pid}
}

(
  # Long execution script example
  echo a
  sleep 1
  echo b >&2
  sleep 1
  echo c >&2
  sleep 1
  echo d
) 2>&1 | outToLog "${log_file}"

# File result
echo '==========='
cat "${log_file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted my solution to this problem here. It does use process substitution and requires Bash > v4 but also captures stdout, stderr and return code into variables you name in the current scope:

https://gist.github.com/pmarreck/5eacc6482bc19b55b7c2f48b4f1db4e8

The whole point of this exercise was so that I could assert on these things in a test suite. The fact that I just spent all afternoon figuring out this simple-sounding thing... I hope one of these solutions helps others!