# Redirect java output with bash script (liquibase)

Tags: java, bash, shell, liquibase

I have a fairly complex piece of bash script to run through different configurations and install lots of Oracle schemas, during which I got to call "liquibase" which is a piece of java software.

What I want to do is completely silence the output from liquibase and handle these outputs conditionally depending on the output.

I try doing this with following way

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(liquibase --"lots of parameters here") > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
echo "from the variable:$output"
```

which does same "some" part of the output, into my variable but still displays some other part on the screen. For example I get:

```
Liquibase 'status' Successful
from the variable:PROCESS10@jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost is up to date
```

As you can see "Liquibase 'status' Successful" is not saved in my variable and written directly to screen.

So how can I redirect/save all output into a variable instead of dumping it to screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
output=$(liquibase --"lots of parameters here") > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

The `STDOUT` and `STDERR` redirections become useless when you say so.  You'd continue to see the `STDERR` on the terminal.

In order to redirect both the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` of the command into the variable, say:

```
output=$(liquibase --"lots of parameters here" 2>&1)
```

In order to redirect the `STDOUT` into the variable and discard the error completely, say:

```
output=$(liquibase --"lots of parameters here" 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: just a side question, do you think I can redirect stdout into a variable and stderror into another variable, without running the liquibase command twice

Comment: @kali [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/bash-store-stdout-and-stderr-in-different-variables) might answer what you want.