# How to use user entered variable value from one shell script to another shell script in linux?

Tags: shell

I have a three shell script.Where I have to use user entered value count from script1.sh to script2.sh. **How can I use user entered value count from script1.sh to script2.sh trhough main.sh?**

scrip1.sh

```
read -p 'Enter a number:' count
```

script2.sh

```
echo "Count:$count"
```

main.sh

```
sleep 1 && ./script1.sh
sleep 1 && ./script2.sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a global variable within a function in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564995/how-to-modify-a-global-variable-within-a-function-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How can I modify a global variable in a sub-shell?***

This is your actual real question.

In short, **you can't!** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564995/how-to-modify-a-global-variable-within-a-function-in-bash))

You want to have your variable `$count` be known to `main.sh` and modified by the sub-shell which executes `script1.sh` and passed to the sub-shell `script2.sh` for reading.

Passing a variable from the parent (`main.sh`) to a child for reading is possible when using `EXPORT` or declaring the variable as global. Eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is main.sh
export count=5
./script2.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is script2.sh
echo "$count"
```

This runs as:

```
$./main.sh
5
```

Modifying the variable is not possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is main.sh
export count=5
./script1.sh
./script2.sh

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is script1.sh
count=7
```

This runs as:

```
$./main.sh
5
```

**What Can you do?**

If you want to modify a variable in parent, you have to ask `script1.sh` to return the value via `/dev/stdout` and then catch it.

And then you have two options:

- *declare `count` a global variable*

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  # This is main.sh
  export count=5
  count=$(./script1.sh)
  ./script2.sh
  ```
- *pass `count` as and argument*

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  # This is main.sh
  count=$(./script1.sh)
  ./script2.sh "$count"

  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  # This is my script2.sh
  count="$1"
  echo "$count"
  ```

This runs as:

```
$./main.sh
7
```

An alternative solution is to make use of `source`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is my main.sh
source ./script1.sh
source ./script2.sh
```

---

> When you execute the script you are opening a new shell, type the commands in the new shell, copy the output back to your current shell, then close the new shell. Any changes to the environment will take effect only in the new shell and will be lost once the new shell is closed.
>
> When you source the script you are typing the commands in your current shell. Any changes to the environment will take effect and stay in your current shell.
>
> **<sub>source: [super user: What is the difference between executing a bash script vs sourcing it](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it)</sub>**

Comment: I just want to export count variable into script2.sh where I have to take different decision based on that variable.@kvantour

Comment: @ARYA1992 I have modified the answer

Comment: script1.sh  not just have count variable there are many more lines and variables.I given that  just as an example.And also I have to execute that whole script1.sh becasue its doing a particular task1 then after I have to do task2 by calling script2.sh where I have to do decision making using that count variable entered by user in script1.sh@kvantour