# Get file owner name whit the use of ls and cut command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently trying create a function that retrieves a files owner name whit the following function:

```
OWNER_IDX=3
fileowner=""

#Gives file owner name. Takes the file name as an argument
function getfileowner()
{
    fileowner=`ls -l | grep $1 | cut -f $OWNER_IDX -d " "`
    echo $fileowner
}
```

To verify what my function does exactly, I created a test function:

```
function testgetfileowner()
{
    for file in `ls`
    do 
        getfileowner $file
        echo "$file belongs to $fileowner"
    done
}
```

But when I execute my script, I get this output:

```
exemple_gz.gz belongs to 
exemple_tar.tar belongs to 
exemple_tgz.tgz belongs to 
exercice_10.sh belongs to 
exercice_8.sh belongs to 
INFOH304 belongs to 
lipap.sh belongs to
```

I test the line

```
fileowner=`ls -l | grep $1 | cut -f $OWNER_IDX -d " "`
```

on a terminal as follows:

```
ls -l  | grep exemple_gz.gz | cut -f 3 -d " "
```

and it works fine. What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't use simply use `stat -c %U $1` ? And even with your code, the `grep` phase is useless, you can directly do `ls -l $1`

Comment: Also instead of ```for file in `ls` ``` write `for file in *`. It is safer and shorter.

Comment: @Geoffroy I'm not allowed to use any command I haven't learned yet. But thanks for the advice, it's much more easy. The reason I use the `grep` phase is because using `ls -l $1` does not work properly when $1 is a folder.

Comment: @genkidesuka `ls -ld` is that case, so it lists the directory itself not its content

Comment: I question a class that can't provide appropriate assignments for the material presented so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564995/how-to-modify-a-global-variable-within-a-function-in-bash) post another solution is to print on stdout instead of returning the value and capture it with a command substitution.

```
#Gives owner name. Takes the file name as an argument
function getfileowner()
{
    echo "`ls -ld $1 | cut -f $OWNER_IDX -d " "`"
}
function testgetfileowner()
{
    for file in *
    do 
        echo "$file belongs to $(getfileowner $file)"
    done
}
```

Comment: The `echo` is not needed in `getfileowner`, as the commands will print on stdout anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`$fileowner` is never set to any value in your test, you should return the value in `getfileowner`.

Also, as I said in the comments, you can directly use `stat -c %U filename`  to get the username.

You have another problem in your function: `ls -l | grep $1` can match several files and is redundant, whereas `ls -dl $1` does what you want directly, the `-d` allowing to list a directory itself, not its content.

Comment: @Geoffoy I returned the value in getfileowner()
with  `echo "\`ls -ld $1 | cut -f $OWNER_IDX -d " "`"\`` 
and retrieved it in my test function as follows 
`echo "$file belongs to $(getfileowner $file)"` as you suggested. And it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's not a return value, you're just printing something on stdout and capturing it on the other side... But yeah it can work this way too, after all.