# Capturing stderr, but not stdout

Tags: bash, shell

In my bash script, I read in a set of lines that look like this

```
arg $PROG arg arg
```

I want to be able to run the line, capture the STDERR as a variable, and prevent either the STDOUT or STDERR from printing to the screen. This is my solution so far but the error variable is always empty.

```
$PROG=/c/Program1
{ error=$($(eval $line) 2>&1 1>&$out); } {out}>&1
echo $error
```

Please explain solutions thoroughly. I am new to bash shell scripting and trying to learn.

Comment: I offered [Store/capture stdout and stderr in different variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11027679) as a duplicate, but you could consider [Redirect stderr and stdout in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script) and [How to pipe stderr and not stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout) too.

Answer (score 8):

For a command that prints to both stdout and stderr like this one:

```
mycommand () { echo "stdout"; echo "stderr" >&2; }
```

If I issue that normally, I see all the output:

```
$ mycommand
stdout
stderr
```

I can redirect stdout or stderr to `/dev/null` so it doesn't get printed:

```
$ mycommand >/dev/null    # Equivalent to 1>/dev/null
stderr
$ mycommand 2>/dev/null
stdout
```

If I want to capture only stderr, I first have to redirect stderr to where stdout out is pointing to at the moment, then redirect stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
error="$(2>&1 1>/dev/null mycommand)"
```

Now `error` only contains output from stderr:

```
$ echo "$error"
stderr
```

The position on the line doesn't really matter, but the order of redirections does, so this has the same effect:

```
error="$(mycommand 2>&1 1>/dev/null)"
```

but this doesn't:

```
error="$(1>/dev/null 2>&1 mycommand)"
```

The last command would redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, and `error` would be empty.

A great resource for redirection is on the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial).

---

A few pointers for what you tried:

- Assignment requires to not use the `$` in the parameter name, so it should be `PROG=/c/Program1` and not `$PROG=/c/Program1`.
- Uppercase variable names are discouraged because they are more likely to clash with environment variables.
- In 99% of the cases, there is a solution that avoids `eval`, see [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) why that is a good idea.

Comment: It doesn't work in some cases? Like process substitution `diff -u <(2>&1 1>/dev/null echo Hello stderr) <(echo Hello stdout)`

Comment: @Sandburg `2>&1 1>/dev/null echo Hello stderr` prints nothing because `echo` prints to stdout, and that is redirected to `/dev/null`. All the examples use `mycommand`, which is a command that prints output to both stdout and stderr.