# How to capture stderr in a variable and pipe stdout through

Tags: bash, shell, curl, stderr

I'm trying to store the headers (from stderr) of a curl response in a variable and pipe the body (from stdout) to grep.

Here's my current attempt:

```
{
  HEADERS=$(curl -vs $URL 2>&1 1>&3-)
  echo "$HEADERS"
} 3>&1 | grep "regex" >> filename
echo "$HEADERS"
```

When I run the script with `bash -x script.sh` I see `+ HEADERS='...'` with the expected output, but I can't access them with either `$HEADERS` nor `"$HEADERS"` inside and outside the inline group.

The body get's piped through as expected.

Comment: So you want the `grep` output to be on terminal or somewhere else?

Comment: `curl -vs -$URL 2>&1 1>&3-` to `curl -vs $URL 2>&1 1>&3-`

Comment: Any reason not to just set header as a variable, then grep the variable instead of this complicated pipe ?

Comment: @anishsane the `grep` output should in this case be appended to `filename`. This part works.

Comment: @123 The variable contains the headers from stderr. The `grep` processes the body from stdout.

Comment: Does [Store/capture stdout and stderr in different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/store-capture-stdout-and-stderr-in-different-variables-bash) actually cover what you need to know?  It's one level more complex because it has both streams caught in variables, but it is otherwise covering very similar territory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) correctly [diagnosed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779658/15168), the problem is that you're setting `HEADERS` in a sub-process, not in the main process of your shell.

You can use Bash's [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to avoid the problem, without using temporary files which have to be cleaned up in the event of the shell being interrupted:

```
HEADERS=""
{ HEADERS=$(curl -vs "$URL" 2>&1 1>&3-); } 3> >(grep "regex" > file)
echo "$HEADERS"
```

The grep sub-process is hidden by the process substitution.  The space between `3>` and `>(…)` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You lose `HEADERS` variable due to use of pipes which forks and runs your piped commands in a sub shell and parent shell doesn't see variable created in child shells.

You can do this via a temporary file:

```
{ f=$(mktemp /tmp/curl.XXXXXX); curl -vs "$URL" 2>"$f" |
grep 'regex' >> filename; HEADERS="$(<$f)"; trap 'rm -f "$f"' EXIT;}
```

Now `HEADERS` variable will be populated in parent shell itself by reading temporary file created using `mktemp`.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to show the `rm -f "$f"` after assigning to `HEADERS`?  What about interrupts, traps and clean up of the file?

Comment: Thanks, I added `trap` to clean the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks for this version, which works as well. I accepted @JonathanLeffler's solution as it avoids temporary files.