# STDOUT of nested commands in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Quite new to bash - I'm trying to store the output of my /usr/bin/time command into the TIME_INFO variable, which works with the below setup... however I would also like to be able to store the output of some of the other nested commands (such as /usr/local/bin/firejail or ./program) to other variables. Currently if there is a runtime exception in ./program it'll also go to the TIME_INFO variable.

```
TIME_INFO=$( /usr/bin/time --quiet -f "%e-%U-%S-%M-%x" 2>&1 \
timeout 5s \
/usr/local/bin/firejail --quiet --cgroup=/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/group1/tasks --profile=java.profile \
./program < test.in > test.out )
```

Is there any way to accomplish separating outputs of multiple nested commands?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is certainly *easiest* with temporary files. Are you okay with their use?

Comment: Yeah, I'm only using the data to make a summary of information for each process that the script runs so that'd be fine.

Comment: See [capture stdout and stderr in different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/store-capture-stdout-and-stderr-in-different-variables-bash) for an idea of what a closely related operation looks like *without* temporary files in use.

Comment: If you aren't looking for the errors , doing `2>&1` inside the `$(...)` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry, I was a bit unclear - the time command outputs to stderr by default according to the man page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to inject a shell in the call chain and make it responsible for modifying stderr for its subprocesses:

```
time_info=$( /usr/bin/time --quiet -f "%e-%U-%S-%M-%x" 2>&1 \
  sh -c '"$@" 2>"$0"' test.err \
    timeout 5s \
      /usr/local/bin/firejail \
          --quiet --cgroup=/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/group1/tasks --profile=java.profile \
        ./program < test.in > test.out )

# read your content back into a shell variable
error_text=$(<test.err)
```

The pertinent change here is `sh -c '"$@" 2>"$0"`, which runs its arguments as a command, with stderr redirected to the filename passed in `$0` -- which is populated from the string immediately following code passed with `sh -c`.

<sub>Note that I modified the case of the `TIME_INFO` variable [per POSIX guidance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) specifying all-caps names for variables with meaning to the shell or OS, and reserving names with at least one lower-case character for other purposes.</sub>

Comment: Could you just leave out stderr entirely ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, sure -- if you used `/dev/null` in place of `test.err`, it would have that effect. I'm not sure that's the OP's intent, though. (Can't discard stderr for the *entire* command because it's where the output of `time` is stored).

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ...that said, you make a point that since it's stderr from `time` that we want to keep, I should really be putting the shim earlier in the call tree.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This works perfect, thank you! Could get a little messy if you wanted to get the output for each individual sub commannd though. Also cheers for the bit on the posix syntax.